# Reducing bit depth on png's generated from video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, images, color-depth

I'm using ffmpeg to pull png image frames from a video:

```
> ffmpeg -i video.mp4 frames%05d.png
```

The png's that result are 24 bit depth, which is too large for my purposes. I would like to use 16 or 8 bit color images, without an alpha channel. I checked:

```
> ffmpeg -h encoder=png
```

which returned:

```
(...)

Supported pixel formats: rgb24 rgba rgb48be rgba64be pal8 gray ya8 gray16be monob

(...)
```

I am unfamiliar with ya8, and gray 16be wouldn't be color. So is it possible to get 8 bit or 16 bit png's from ffmpeg conversion?

Comment: 24-bit is already without alpha. Alpha [or strictly, transparency; it's not true alpha] makes them 32-bit. Why don't you just use jpg if you want smaller files, let the algorithm decide how many colours it needs to discard?

Comment: In this case, I have the constraint of needing to use png format.

Answer (score 1):

Using a 256 color palette will give you a smaller output.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -pix_fmt pal8 frames%05d.png
```

Almost as small will be a 24-bit output funneled through a 256-color palette first.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf format=pal8 -pix_fmt rgb24 frames%05d.png
```